# How do I display the selected item and use borders with a combobox? And why does this behavior occur?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, wpf-controls, selecteditem

How do I make the selected item of a `ComboBox` show up in the `ComboBox` textfield AND use `Border`s in the `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`? With the following code the items popup fine but never show up in the `ComboBox` textfield after selecting; but removing the 2 `Border`s from the `ComboBox` template fixes this. Why?? How?? And more importantly: how do I use this template with `Border`s AND have the `SelectedItem` show up properly in the `ComboBox` textfield after selecting?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboboxDropdownButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="NaN"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <DockPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                               LastChildFill="False">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" 
                                DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                                CornerRadius="0,3,3,0"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                >
                            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M0,0L4.5,4 9,0z"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"
           TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                            x:Name="OuterBorder" 
                            Background="Transparent" 
                            BorderBrush="Red" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Margin="-1">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" 
                                Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                CornerRadius="3" 
                                BorderBrush="Black">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                               Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                               Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                                              Margin="-1"
                                              Grid.Column="2"
                                              Focusable="False"
                                              ClickMode="Press"
                                              Style="{StaticResource ComboboxDropdownButton}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                                  Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                </ContentPresenter>
                                <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                         Style="{x:Null}"
                                         Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                         Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                         Focusable="True"
                                         Background="Transparent"
                                         Visibility="Hidden"
                                         IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                                       Placement="Bottom"
                                       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                       AllowsTransparency="True"
                                       Focusable="False"
                                       PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                    <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                          >
                                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                                MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Border}" 
                                                Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                                                BorderBrush="Black" 
                                                BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3">
                                        </Border>
                                        <ScrollViewer Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="120" Height="20" Name="comboBox1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Text="ComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True">
        <ComboBoxItem>item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just a completely wild guess... we had same situation few months back when combobox popup and selection did not show up intermittently in our custom combobox template with borders and it went off when we removed the `CornerRadius` property from the Border.... :-/  ... I know sounds stupid and totally ridiculous but thats what actually happened! Its a mistery I couldnt solve till date... AND you can downvote me if this "hopeless" trick doesnt work.... :-D

Comment: The same strange thing happened to me once. Also weird: in .NET 3.0, we had a DropShadowBitmap effect on a TextBlock. It caused a memory leak that would cause our app to increase by about 1 MB / minute.

Comment: Yep! That too! Our Splash screen had both Rounded Corners and DropShadowBitmap and a Combobox on it acted totally absurd! When we removed the two, it started working fine!

Comment: no the cornerradius is not the problem, even when I remove the cornerradius everywhere and add just 2 basic borders without setting any of their properties this still happens. only when I completely remove the 2 borders the selected item is shown, but then I've lost the looks I need on the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this.. by removing the borders from the template. I replaced the borders with rectangles in the grid of the template. Worked like a charm. The result can be found in the next question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980586/remove-combobox-selected-item-text-highlighting).