# remove combobox selected item text highlighting

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I've already found a lot of questions about manipulating the highlight of items to select in the dropdown of the combobox or overriding system brushes. This is NOT what I'm after.. I want to get rid of the text highlighting of the selected item shown in the combobox textfield after selecting. But I do not want to get rid of the text highlighting in the dropdown! So overriding the system brushes is not what I need because that also affects the items in the dropdown. Below is XAML for a complete test project. Build + run and select an item to see the effects. The text of any selected item in the combobox textfield will be highlighted with a light grayish brush. That's what I want to get rid of.. but how..?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboboxDropdownButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="NaN"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <DockPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                                   Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                   LastChildFill="False">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                                    Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" 
                                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                                    Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                                    CornerRadius="0,3,3,0"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                      >
                            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M0,0L4.5,4 9,0z"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                    Margin="-1"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Focusable="False"
                    ClickMode="Press"
                    Style="{StaticResource ComboboxDropdownButton}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                    Style="{x:Null}"
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                    Focusable="True"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Visibility="Hidden"
                    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="-3" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="-1" Fill="BlanchedAlmond" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                    Placement="Bottom"
                    IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                    AllowsTransparency="True"
                    Focusable="False"
                    PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=BackgroundVisualElement}" 
                                Background="BlanchedAlmond" 
                                BorderBrush="Black" 
                                BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3">
                                <ScrollViewer>
                                    <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Margin="0,0,363,221" />
    <ComboBox Width="120" Height="20" Name="comboBox1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True">
        <ComboBoxItem>item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT:** for better effect, add Foreground="Transparent" to the PART_EditableTextBox. The selected item in the combobox textfield will still show up highlighted with the light grayish brush I want to get rid of..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using WPF 4 you can set the `SelectionBrush` of the `TextBox` to `Transparent`

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
         SelectionBrush="Transparent"
         .../>
```

You can read more about `SelectionBrush` here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/28/selection-brush.aspx