# Disable Highlighting Text in ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've added some display text to my combo box, but I want to remove the ability to highlight it. The cursor automatically displays as the "text" style cursor when hovering over the text. I tried doing IsHitTestVisable=false as another answer suggested, but this just removes the ability to interact with the combobox at all.

```
<Window x:Class="msmExe.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:msmExe"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Home" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="446" Margin="33,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="831" Opacity="0.695" Source="./Images/homepage.png"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboDiskInstructions" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="55" Margin="0,172,86.333,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" RenderTransformOrigin="0.55,2.63" Background="#FFD1D1D1" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Instructions" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Sans Serif Collection" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Opacity="0.9" Focusable="False" IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged="cboInstructions_MouseOverDirectlyChanged" MouseEnter="cboInstructions_MouseEnter" >
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Button x:Name="Instructions1" Content="Instructions 1" Width="170" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Click="Instructions1_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Instructions2" Content="NFS UNDERGROUND" Width="170" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Click="Instructions2_Click"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="buttonMain" Content="TEXT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="83,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Background="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif Collection" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Opacity="0.9" Click="buttonMain_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove combobox selected item text highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980586/remove-combobox-selected-item-text-highlighting)

Comment: No, selection brush is not a property of a combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but try this implementation.

```xml
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Instructions" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Button Content="Instructions 1"/>
        <Button Content="NFS UNDERGROUND"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

**P.S.** Conceptually, it is not at all clear why buttons are used here. ComboBox is a Selector. That is, a control for selecting an element from a collection. If you just need a drop-down list of buttons, then you should use Expander or even Menu.

Comment: I don't need buttons I just used that because that was the default when adding items to the drop down. I used it because of how it works visually. What should be used instead? A combo box item for all three? Thank you!

Comment: I changed all of them to be combobox items and changed the event handler on the buttons from click to selected and it works perfectly, thank you!